# Is there a clean way to access hash values in array of hashes?

Tags: ruby

In this code:

```
arr = [ { id: 1, body: 'foo'}, { id: 2, body: 'bar' }, { id: 3, body: 'foobar' }]
arr.map { |h| h[:id] } # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Is there a cleaner way to get the values out of an array of hashes like this?

[Underscore.js has pluck](http://underscorejs.org/), I'm wondering if there is a Ruby equivalent.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you don't mind monkey-patching, you can go pluck yourself:

```
arr = [{ id: 1, body: 'foo'}, { id: 2, body: 'bar' }, { id: 3, body: 'foobar' }]

class Array
  def pluck(key)
    map { |h| h[key] }
  end
end

arr.pluck(:id)
=> [1, 2, 3]
arr.pluck(:body)
=> ["foo", "bar", "foobar"]
```

Furthermore, it looks like [someone has already generalised this for Enumerables](https://gist.github.com/ktheory/1839796), and someone else [for a more general solution](http://kourge.net/node/100).

Comment: While I feel `pluck` is a useful addition, the addition of `invoke` semantics in the "more general solution" link is pretty silly in Ruby, since `Symbol#to_proc` takes care of it for you.  `[1,2,3,4].map &:to_s` works with no monkey-patching.

Comment: The `Symbol#to_proc`/`[].map &:method_name` shortcut won't help with `hash[key]`, because `Hash#[]` needs the key parameter.

Answer (score 14):

Now rails support `Array.pluck` out of the box. It has been implemented by this [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20350)

It is implemented as:

```
def pluck(key)
  map { |element| element[key] }
end
```

So there is no need to define it anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

Unpopular opinion maybe, but I wouldn't recommend using `pluck` on `Array` in Rails projects since it is also implemented by `ActiveRecord` and it behaves quite differently in the ORM context (it changes the `select` statement) :

```rb
User.all.pluck(:name) # Changes select statement to only load names
User.all.to_a.pluck(:name) # Loads the whole objects, converts to array, then filters the name out
```

Therefore, to avoid confusion, I'd recommend using the shorten `map(&:attr)` syntax **on arrays**:

```rb
arr.map(&:name)
```

Comment: What do you mean, `User.all.pluck(:name) != User.all.to_a.pluck(:name)`? These work differently, yes, but should produce identical arrays.

Comment: Indeed it should, but one might experience some odds behaviors with complex queries (chained scopes, group by, custom select, etc.). Just wanted to warn people that there are two `pluck` implementations in rails context and they are quite different :
- https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/pluck
- https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck
Also `map(&:attr)` performs caching, while `fetch(:attr)` always reruns the query on the database.

Comment: "but one might experience some odds behaviors" - no, I don't think so. I can't think of a query that would make these two diverge. I am very interested in seeing one.

Comment: `User.all.map(&:name)` is a terribly wasteful way of fetching just one column, btw. Waste all around: bandwidth, memory footprint, CPU time.

Comment: Yes, in most cases, i would recommend using `pluck` with `ActiveRecord` and `map` with arrays, just to avoid confusion (`pluck` is just an alias to `map` with arrays, while `pluck` and `map` behave very differently with `ActiveRecord`). That was the point.
Finnally, in order to answer your interest :
This works : `User.select('COUNT(*) AS role_count').group(:"users.role").map(&:role_count)`
This doesn't : `User.select('COUNT(*) AS role_count').group(:"users.role").pluck(:role_count
)` (`ERROR:  column "role_count" does not exist`)

Comment: I wouldn't call that "odd behaviour", but I accept this :+1:

Comment: "pluck is just an alias to map with arrays" - it's not. It is implemented in terms of `map`, but it's not equivalent. Anyway, thanks for responding to this. I still don't agree with the recommendation, of course, but someone might :)

Comment: To be clear: the two approaches should always return the same value, but depending on the query and the underlying data, one might perform massively better than the other (in the extreme case, the worse one might consume all available memory and raise an OOME), and I think the "odd behavior" in question was referring to the potential to be surprised by that poor performance when the developer is accustomed to the behavior being indistinguishable for trivial cases.